# Runtime Error: Object Expected

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI which is doing simple autocomplete function. Autocomplete is coming via Web Service.

This is the sample of my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id$="tbSearch"]').autocomplete({
        url: '/WebService/SearchLookUp.asmx/ReturnEntity',
        width: 300,
        max: 10,
        delay: 100,
        cacheLength: 1,
        scroll: false,
        highlight: false
    });
});
```

And this is the sample of my web service:

```
 public class SearchLookUp : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string []ReturnEntity(string prefixText)
    {
        using (TestDataContext search = new TestDataContext())
        {
            var tr = from p in search.Entities
                     where p.Name.StartsWith(prefixText)
                     select p.Name;
            return tr.ToArray<string>();
        }

    }

}
```

When I am running this web service in the browser and passing parameters: 'ST' I am getting these results:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <string>Steve</string> 
  <string>Star</string> 
  <string>Steve D</string> 
  <string>Star Route</string> 
  <string>Staffing</string> 
  <string>Strategic</string> 
  <string>Staci</string> 
  <string>Stevens</string> 
  <string>Starr</string> 
  </ArrayOfString>
```

Now the problem is that as soon I am entering anything on my textbox (tbSearch) I am getting MS jScript Error: Object Expected in

> jQuery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js

At line this:

```
{this.pending++;this.element.addClass("ui-autocomplete-loading");this.source({term:a},this.response)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to check your syntax on the autocomplete object

based on this [TextBox AutoComplete with ASP.NET and jQuery UI](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515)

`source:` method is built to call the ajax, looks like you also need to specify the `data:` to be sent to the web service